# jupyter ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython'

Tags: jupyter

I recently upgraded `jupyter`, but now I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython'
```

when I run for instance `jupyter-notebook` or `jupyter notebook`

and `pip install --upgrade pyzmq` did not solve the issue

any idea?

Thanks

ps: I am on Mac OS 10.15.5 , with `jupyter --v`:

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.5.5
ipython          : 8.0.0.dev
ipykernel        : not installed
jupyter client   : not installed
jupyter lab      : 1.2.3
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: ok, I had two python v. 3.7 and 3.8 – I removed 3.7 and now it's 'fine' (I still have to link the kernel, etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and below fixed my problem:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Anaconda environment, please try executing the command:

```
conda install pyzmq
```

Answer (score -1):

This actually worked. If you are launching jupyter-notebook from a venv and you get this error message, just pip unistall pyzmq and pip install pyzmq. You should be fine.

Comment: you mean `pyzmq` ?